# Get url from iframe or any other control

Tags: asp.net

I've an aspx page with an iframe control which host cross domain site. I'would provide a simple tool to allow user a fast "copy-past" frame url in an asp.net textbox.
Obviously, since my IFrame point to external site this kind of action is denied for security reasons.

Is there any way to get current frame url in a cross domain scenario?

I can use whichever different solution from iframe, it really isn't important for me.

Comment: Some code would be nice. In general you can set iframe's url to whatever you want - this does not fall under the same origin policy. What you can't do is you cannot access iframe's content

Comment: I don't want set iframe's url. I want fetch current ifram's url after user navigation, just when user click on my parent page button, but something like document.getElementById('iframeID').contentWindow.location.href throws a security exception due to cross domain url.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for javascript solution then this could be it:
HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="url" />
<button id="go">Go</button>
<br />
<iframe id="browser" width="300px" height="300px"></iframe>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#go").on("click", function(){
        var url = $("#url").val();
        $("#browser").attr("src", url);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bBhc4/

"Diving deeper" into iframe elements would cause same origin policy restrictions though

Comment: No. It's not good. My scenario is different. Final user can navigate through web page iframe contained in and my button click should show me current url. Since frame url is cross domain, I achieve a security exception.